# ScheduledExecutorService - Check if the task already scheduled with same time

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduledexecutorservice

I have two tasks which are scheduled twice a day with different timings.

> Example:
>
> 1. Task1 scheduled for 11AM and 3PM
> 2. Task2 scheduled for 2PM and 5PM

I want to check whether the task is already has been scheduled for the same time or not ?

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(MYTHREADS);

        String[] hostList = { "http://crunchify.com","http://yahoo.com"}; //Two Tasks
        String[] timings = {"11:0,15:0","10:0,17:0"}; //(11AM,3PM) and (10AM,5PM) scheduled timings twice a day

        for (int i = 0; i < hostList.length; i++) {
            String url = hostList[i];           
            Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(url);
            String[] schedulingHour = timings[i].split(",");            
            for(int j=0;j<schedulingHour.length;j++){
                executor1.schedule(worker,getTimeUntilTarget(Integer.parseInt(schedulingHour[j].split(":")[0]),Integer.parseInt(schedulingHour[j].split(":")[1])), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            }               

        }
```

Comment: Are you trying to check if the scheduler is already running in a different JVM process or in the same one ?

Comment: I am trying to check in the same JVM

Comment: Easiest way would be to give the schedulers some ID like `crunchify` and `yahoo` and put them in a `ConcurrentHashMap` when they're scheduled. Before scheduling check if the ID already exists. A better way would be to store this information in a database, that way different processes would also be in sync.